# Visual Studio freezes on running C++ Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2015, freeze

I have Visual Studio 2015 and I want to develop C++ programs. Two months earlier everything was working fine, but if I try to run an application now VS freezes. If I only build the solution it sais that the built was ok. But starting the Debugger freezes VS. Also when I copy the .exe output and run it without VS, the command line freezes. I tried deinstalling VS and deleting every piece it left on my PC and reinstalling VS, but this wasn't working either. So I really don't know what to do anymore. Please help!

Comment: Do you have Avast antivirus running? It may block your generated executables. Read this: [Stop avast! from attacking my own programs](http://superuser.com/questions/555905/stop-avast-from-attacking-my-own-programs)

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. (: